# PJAX doesn't load script modules

Tags: javascript, module, pjax

I'm trying to incorporate javascript modules into a site that uses PJAX, e.g.:

`<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>`

I'm finding that when I navigate to these pages from another page in the site, the modules never load. They do load if I refresh the page. Is there a way to ensure that modules like this work with PJAX here?

Answer (score 0):

If you use this file in one page only. call this file in the **#pjax-container** not outside the container. for more information check [this](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/issues/648).